# Adding contacts to Sendgrid using PHP doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have been trying to use the SendGrid API to add contacts to a particular list (List ID) from the content the user places inna form.

I have created a form with the correct field names and ID, then wrote some PHP.

No errors come up on the PHP, but no contact gets added to the Sendgrid List. Can some one help me determine what is wrong with my code, no doubt I'm missing something.

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    
$first_name = $_POST['firstName']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['lastName']; // required
$email = $_POST['email']; // required

$honeypot = $_POST['Lastname'];
    
if(!empty( $honeypot ) ){
    echo "The information you have entered is not in the correct format or you are a bot. The information you entered has not been submitted.";
    return; 
    
} else {
            
    $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",


  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"list_ids\":[\"8266d64e-64e1-4ee6-a23c-bf93be742d18\"],\"contacts\":[{\"email\":\"$email\",\"first_name\":\"$first_name\",\"last_name\":\"$last_name\"}]}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer MY-API-KEY",
        "content-type: application/json"

  ),
));
    
    echo "test";        
}       }
```

Comment: Don't build your JSON like that - it's grim, unreadable, very error-prone, and very difficult to validate. Build the data structure in a PHP object/array and then json_encode it. That's more flexible, easier to write code for, easier to validate, and guarantees correct JSON output every time.

Comment: Anyway...is this all your code? I don't see anywhere that you actually execute the cURL request or check what response you got from it. Make sure what you've provided us is really a [mre] of your issue.

Comment: P.S. SendGrid has a PHP client library for their API...it would almost certainly make your life easier to use that instead of trying to build all the necessary HTTP requests by hand. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php . Apart from anything else, you can then easily base your code on the PHP examples in the documentation (e.g. https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact?code-sample=code-add-or-update-a-contact&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=%26gt%3B5.6), which increases your chances of getting it right first time.

Comment: That is all the code I have. I’ve been trying to get this to work from the sendgrid PHP documentation, but am new to all this. My question was how do I make it work. If you can supply a basic example of the PHP code to use that would allow me to add a contact to a list on sendgrid using the API Key, that would be helpful. 

Comment: `That is all the code I have`...well then like I said you have not actually executed the cURL request. Therefore no data is ever sent to sendGrid. All you've done is set the options for the request. Studying almost any example or tutorial about PHP curl would show you what to do to execute it. For reference also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: Also https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: But as I said also, using the ready-made sendGrid PHP library might be easier in the long run, especially if you're planning to do a bigger integration involving multiple different calls to the API.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to use the links you sent and work out how to execute the code. It now adds the contact to sendgrid. You mention the ready made sendgrid PHP library. I did try that before this one, but despite adding the API Key it kept saying it required authentication. So that why I went down the route of using a header authentication. Thanks again for you suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that I wasn’t executing anything. Thanks for comments, they helped me work it out.